# Jquery function is executed only once

Tags: jquery

I've a jquery script to remove articles from a shopping cart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(".deleteLink").click(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'delete.php',
                data: "id=" +id
            })
            .done(function(data){
                alert("Deleted.");
                var url="basket.php";
                $("#warenkorb").load(" #warenkorb > *");
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert("Error");
            }); 
            return false;  
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works when I enter the page and click on a Delete-Link. When I click on the second link it does not work anymore. I have to reload the page. Then I can delete again exactly once.

The Link looks like this:

```
<a class="deleteLink" data-id="$id" href="#">Delete</a>
```

Could anybody imagine what the problem could be?

Comment: Use $(".deleteLink").on.("click", function(e) { ... } because you change the content of your shopping cart dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
When I use
$(".deleteLink").on.("click", function(e) { ...
unfortunately nothing happens when I click on the link (not even the first time)

Comment: Use `$(document).on("click", ".deleteLink", function(e) { ... }`

Comment: have you check console log if any occur in it?

Comment: When I remove
$("#warenkorb").load(" #warenkorb > *");
the items are deleted correctly, but the shopping cart is not updated od course.

Comment: @Roy
That was the solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(document).on("click", ".deleteLink", function(e) { ... }`

> Documentation:   [$(document).on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
>   The **.on()** method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see .one()